# Resolve Error 000210 when using Scratch Workspace?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.0, error-000210, scratch-workspace

Now I'm trying to make Python script to resolve some problem.

I need too place all out features in Scratch Workspace (Later this script will be used in web GIS and intermediate features mustn't be saved).
But when I'm trying to do this i have and 000210 error.

How can i resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Please edit your Question to include the actual code formatted rather than a picture of it. The former is easy to copy/paste to try and fix, the latter requires re-typing which will be off putting to potential answerers.

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce your problem. This seems to be a bug since the [scratchworkspace page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Scratch_Workspace/001w00000003000000/) says:

> *If the scratch workspace environment is set, the autogenerated output path will be the scratch workspace.*

There are 2 workarounds:

1. Mention the full path to the output:

   `import arcpy, os
   ...
   arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(table, os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace, "table1"))`
2. Create a new geodatabase, set the current workspace to it (`arcpy.env.workspace`) and delete the geodatabase at the end of your script:

Comment: What does the first code do? http://yadi.sk/d/Mme8dEeCSEKUh 
It stil don't work

Comment: Do you mean the first line? It imports the os module used to join both parts of the output path. you could also replace `os.path.join(arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace, "table1")` with `arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace + "\table1"` but using `os.path.join` will work whatever the separator is (\ or \\ or /).

Comment: Error 000210 again

Comment: Weird, this solved the issue for me. Check that you have write access to the location and that the output doesn't exist yet. Use maybe a gdb name that doesn't start with a number, sometimes ARcGIS doesn't like it (wasn't a problem for me but I'm using 10.2.2)

Comment: look at link in first comment. Do i do everything right?

Comment: OK... if you want to copy a table, use CopyRows not CopyFeatures.

Comment: It's a feature class, but it don't work(

Comment: You code looks right. If you've changed the gdb name, check access rights and existence of output and it still doesn't work, then try the 2nd workaround.

Comment: I've tried everything and tried it on another PC. Error again( I cannot afford 2d workaround, coz this script will later be used by several users and i cannot make a new GDB